# Declaring global variable php (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

In wordpress `functions.php` file I've following variable:

```
$MediSHOP_settings_db_theme = (get_option("MediSHOP_settings"));
```

But when I try to echo it inside `footer.php` nothing is displayed:

```
<?php echo $MediSHOP_settings_db_theme['shoptel']; ?>
```

Unless I declare it as global inside footer.php

Is there a way to make this variable persistent so I don't have to declare this variable as global inside header.php, footer.php, and index.php and other template files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap important things like this in a `class`. So declaring this vars as sooner as possible, maybe at `init` hook:

```
$this->MediSHOP_settings_db_theme = (get_option("MediSHOP_settings"));
```

will easily available in footer.php

```
<?php $this->MediSHOP_settings_db_theme: ?>
```

Recommend tut: http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-oop-class-framework/